# What is garbage collection and how does it work?

Tags: memory-management, garbage-collection

Forgetting the languages that support this, what is garbage collection all about? How it is implemented in programming languages? How it works and why it's beneficial? Why does languages support (and don't support) it?

Comment: have you read the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science))?

Answer (score -1):

Have you ever used the C programming language? You might notice that, unless you know how much memory you need ahead of time, you have to do `malloc()` and `free()` to get and release memory, respectively. Wouldn't it be cool if your language did that for you?

Enter garbage collection. A GC algorithm traverses through currently-used memory and gets rid of stuff that's not being used. An easy one to learn how it works is the [Mark/Sweep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracing_garbage_collection#Na.C3.AFve_mark-and-sweep) algorithm. It marks objects that are currently being used, then sweeps away stuff that is no longer referenced or in scope. That's beneficial because now you (the programmer) don't have to worry about memory handling! (By the way, don't actually use Mark/Sweep; as of 2016, Java uses the more nuanced [GC1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/g1_gc.html#garbage_first_garbage_collection) algorithm. You can see all the GC algorithms Java has available [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/index.html))

Except you still do. I may program a data structure that *technically* can still access some part of memory, even though semantically it's not possible nor will it be done in the lifetime of the code. But that's not computed at compile-time or run-time, so this bit of unused memory still hangs around. And I might say "Whatever let GC handle it" or worse, I'm completely ignorant of GC and I just make objects wherever I please. This leads to "memory leaks", which is what Garbage Collection was made to prevent in the first place!

As for why some languages don't support it, either its developers believe it's a waste of CPU cycles, or they find memory leaks at compile-time (somehow??), or no good GC algorithms were known when the language was created.